# More efficient string Manipulation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm not good with string manipulation and I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to achieve the result I get below from the following string (from a column called [Details]):

```
 'Probability changed from: [Blank], to: Low. Est Settlement Date changed from: [Blank], to: 2012.'
```

So I wanted only the 2012 part and I got it using the following code:

```
ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(rIGHT(details,LEN(details)-CHARINDEX('to: ',details,Charindex('Settlement Date changed from: [Blank],',details,0))),':',''),'.',''))) as t
```

This is not important as I get the result I need but as I try and grasp string manipulation, I would be interested to see how people with proper brains do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this enough if you only want 2012?

```
SUBSTRING([Details], LEN([Details]) - 5, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX)='Probability changed from: [Blank], to: Low. Est Settlement Date changed from: [Blank], to: 2012.'
SELECT LEFT(RIGHT(@str,5),4)
```

Comment: Ha! THat's great! Thank you Sir!